# MFC catch Control's Message of child from parent without create class handler for child?

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog, cdialog, message-map

I have a CDialog created by wizard named **CDialogParent**, then create a child dialog template has **IDD= IDD_CHILD_DLG1**, in this child dialog I put one button **IDC_BTN1** (I don't create class handler for this child).

```
BOOL CDialogParent::OnInitDialog()
{
  ....
  CDialog *pChild = new CDialog();
  pChild->Create(IDD_CHILD_DLG1, this);
  pChild->ShowWindow(SW_NORMAL);
}
```

Normally, I need to create new class handler **CDialogChild** for child and add message map like:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CDialogChild, CDialog)
      ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BTN1, &CDialogChild::OnBnClickedBtn1)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Problem that I want to catch control's message IDC_BTN1 of child dialog **BUT** by declare message map in CDialogParent like:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CDialogParent, CDialog)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BTN1, &CDialogParent::OnBnClickedBtn1)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

How to do this without create new class handler?
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

In short: You cannot.

There are 2 reasons why this is not possible:

1. Control IDs are unique among siblings (i.e. controls sharing the same parent window) only. Different dialogs can use the same ID for different controls.
2. I'll assume you mean *Owned dialog* when you say *Child dialog* (those are different concepts, but the following rationale is the same). When setting up an owner-owned window relationship, that relationship is based on window handles (`HWND`). There is no additional C++ type information available. Both the type and object pointer are required to call the appropriate class member in a message map.

If you want to be informed about an event raised in an owned dialog, implement a message handler in the owned dialog's class and post a message to the owning dialog.